# Focus between router(navigation) links and components by pressing keyboard Tab key using ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I'm developing single page web application using ReactJS, Redux, Redux-Saga, And the navigation links are created using react-router.

How to focus between router(navigation) links and components by pressing keyboard tab key using react js?

[image]

Comment: erm... add an href or tabindex to the link. Or am I missing something...

Comment: Tried adding tabindex but no luck

Comment: Weird, focusing links on tab press should be the default behavior. Can you share your code? What browser and OS are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Used **focus-trap-react** module to set the tabIndex in React App, Referred this github tutorial: https://github.com/davidtheclark/focus-trap-react